# QGIS 3.4 won't load Python

Tags: qgis-3

I have a problem running QGIS 3.4.11 Madeira properly. I am getting this error on startup. [image: First error]

Now I know this has been asked probably before but I can't seem to find an answer that works for me. Problems started only after I downloaded PyQT5 in my PyCharm. I think that by doing that pythonpath was overwritten somehow and now QGIS isn't loading the module properly, alas I don't know how to proceed. Also I am running it on Windows 10 if that is of any importance.

Comment: Can you try launching it using the "qgis.bat" file, should be in the QGIS install folder or in a "bin" folder.

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto I found qgis.bat file in OSGeo4W64 folder, it started QGIS 3.8 but with same error and then found qgis-ltr.bat in QGIS in bin folder and it started QGIS 3.4 with same result

Comment: PyQt5 should already be included with QGIS install.  Maybe try unintall/re-install.

Comment: It looks like you have multiple versions of QGIS? The error message looks to be pointing to a stand alone install, but you say you tried qgis.bat from an OSGeo4W install.

Comment: I tried reinstalling 2 times through control panel, 3.4 is the only QGIS showing up, I will try to look for the other one if it's installed somewhere without being listed.

Comment: you can have both 3.4 and 3.8 installed without a problem. But installing PyQt5 after qgis is dangerous, this has to be installed by QGIS to match certain pathes and a correct qt.conf. Try to delete all files in the osgeo4w directory, after uninstalling qgis.